# Need help in writing this multiplication code

Tags: c, formatting, output, multiplication, spaces

I need to show process of multiplication in output.for ex:-
inputs are two numbers(say 325 and 4405)
the output would be:-

```
    325
  *4405
  -----
   1625
     0
 1300
1300
-------
1431625
```

NOTE:-number of spaces should be minimum.

I don't need the exact code.
Just tell me which property or way I should be using to get the SPACE right in each line.or how should i proceed to get output.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on using ***[printf format specifiers](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)*** in C.   (not the down voter)      In particular, note the examples such as `printf("%03d\n",b);`  (provides leading space in front of a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @ryyker .Was looking for something of this sort,but wasn't able to find it.But how to it when inputs vary?(i.e. when no of spaces are variable in each input)

Comment: How are the numbers input?  via user input using scanf()?, read from a file?  if as a string, you can use strlen() to know length that will eventually be converted to number.  Or, if working with numeric values, you can test for ranges: `if(x<10) else if((x>=10)&&(x<100) else if...`

Comment: @ryyker thanks for helping again. numbers are taken from the user using scanf().

Comment: Thanks @ryyker .Please put the example,It will be of great help.

Comment: See my example below to see how you can make constant length printouts.  Its simple, but you can extrapolate beyond this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to make constant length printouts using printf:

```
int main(void)
{

    char a[6][7]={"1","22","333","4444","55555","666666"};
    int i;
    int value;

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);i++)
    {
        value = atoi(a[i]);
        printf("%07d\n", value); //with leading zeros
        printf("% 7d\n", value); //with spaces
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: THANKS @ryyker THANK U VERY MUCH.THIS REALLY HELPED.I think I can do it now.